# Adding Total in cro_cpct

Tags: r

```
dataa<-data.frame(
  aa = c("q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c","q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c"),
col1=c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,2,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,2,5,3,5),
col2=c(2,1,1,7,4,1,2,7,5,7,2,6,2,2,6,3,4,3,2,5,7,5,6,4,4,6,5,6,4,1,7,3,2,7,7,2,3,7,2,4)
)
```

do we any solution where i can add total ratio for all variables in cro_cpct summary

```
  df <- database %>% select(!!var1,!!var2)
  tab1 <- expss::cro_cpct(df[[1]],df[[2]])
```

Comment: What does it mean 'add total ratio'? Could you show the desired result?

Comment: like we have total in  

TT= TT <- mtcars %>%
  tab_cols(total(), vs, am) %>%
  tab_stat_cpct() %>%
  tab_pivot()

Comment: like we have total in  

```TT= TT <- mtcars %>%
  tab_cols(total(), vs, am) %>%
  tab_stat_cpct() %>%
  tab_pivot()
```

Comment: but this total is for multi response table so i am looking for solution if we have for single variable column

Comment: Perhaps i misunderstand something, but  total for single response variable don't differ from from total with multiple response. Could you provide the screenshot of desired table?

Comment: just updated the required summary

Comment: `calc_cro_cpct(dataa, aa, list(total(), col1, col2))` gives that: https://i.imgur.com/NPpG8mS.png What is the difference with your desired result?

Comment: col1 and col2 are two different calculated variable , i need for aa (categorical variable ) and col2 (calculated variable)

Comment: i have taken example of col1 and col2 because summary is small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done other data frame and then joined with table, do we have any other solution for this,simplest and easy...??

```
tab1 <- as.data.frame(tab1)
  overall <- as.data.frame(table(dat1[[1]])) %>% adorn_totals()
  overall <- overall %>% mutate(Freq_pct = (Freq / last(Freq))*100) %>% select(1,3)
  overall[[2]] <- format(round(overall[[2]],digits = 1),nsmall = 1)
  #overall[nrow(overall),2] <- colSums(as.data.frame(dat1[[1]]))
  tab1 <- left_join(tab1,overall,by=c("row_labels"="Var1")) %>% select(c("row_labels","Total"=Freq_pct,everything()))
  tab1 <- as.data.frame(tab1)
```